# Issue when submitting a param into controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

This is something I cannot figure out for a while:

In my view I wrote like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("PIndex","Home")){
    <select name ="particalview">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
    </select>
```

The Controller behind it is:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PIndex(string i) {
            if (i == "1")
                ViewBag.Page = 1;
            else if(i == "2")
                ViewBag.Page = 2;

            if(i == null)
                ViewBag.Page = 3;

            return View();
        }
```

Whatever I select, the controller fails to get the param of select list, Can anyone tell me where I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the parameter in PIndex to particalview

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PIndex(string particalview) {
            if (particalview == "1")
                ViewBag.Page = 1;
            else if(particalview == "2")
                ViewBag.Page = 2;

            if(particalview == null)
                ViewBag.Page = 3;

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: why param name makes a difference here?

Comment: Because it connects the select list name to the variable